# Password to be hashed during PATCH request

Tags: express, mongoose

During patch request, along with other changes (e.g. "name" and "email" if required) password changed and then to be hashed.

I have the following code so far patch route:

```
router.patch("/edit/:_id", (req, res, next) => {
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id : req.params._id},
    {$set:
       {
         email: req.body.email,
         name: req.body.name,
         password: req.body.password
       },
     },
     {
       new : true,
       upsert: true,
       omitUndefined: true
     }
   )
  .then(user => res.json(user))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Model/Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

I want to use "bcryptjs" to hash user's password. Please en-light me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it in the payload in plain text? You'll need to hash it either way, using the same salt, otherwise you *can't* find out whether or not it's changed. But I'd probably handle changing passwords separately, and avoid including the hash in the user payload.

Comment: Can you give me some code?

Comment: For what? I'm not writing this for you, I'm trying to establish what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Notice how your question was reworded and next time attempt to repeat its structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did in order to solve, add findOneandUpdate pre hooks on schema.

Here is code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
  type: String,
  required: true
   },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
   },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
   },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
   }
});

UserSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function (next) {
    await this.updateOne({},{ $set: { password: bcrypt.hashSync(this.getUpdate().$set.password, 10) }})
  });

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```